# Using ng-if to hide a certain element

Tags: angular

I have a list of email that my user is related to, in this list there is my email, sometimes my email is on the first position sometimes it's on the middle.
I want to display all emails except mine.

Dashboard.html

```
   <ion-item *ngFor="let sender of email.senders" class="user">
      <div *ngIf="sender.firstname?.length>0" class="firstname">{{ sender.firstname }}</div>
      <div [class.email-nofirstname]="!sender.firstname?.length>0" class="email">{{ sender.email }}</div>
      <ion-icon (click)="deleteUser(sender.email)" name="close" item-end></ion-icon>
    </ion-item>
```

Schema.json

```
"admin": "56d4657ed1327z7a4",
"senders": [
    "56d4657ed1327z7a4",
    "d4d7zscbr879ddda4",
    "sdklmkz778Sdlsma7",
    "sd563dsmlZklks7as",
    "sd5s5465z7dds46q1",
    "sd456576zds<32x1w"
]
```

In this exemple my email is in the first position i can do a slice(1)

But sometimes it's randomly in the list so i don't know how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

Don't put this logic in the markup, do it in your TS file.

Something like this:

```
filteredSenders = this.senders.filter(x => x !== this.admin);
```

---

```
... *ngFor="let sender of filteredSenders" ...
```

Of course, modify the syntax so that it matches yours.

Answer (score 0):

You can try with `ng-container` add `*ng-if` condition in `ion-item` element.

```
<ng-container *ngFor="let sender of email.senders">
    <ion-item *ngIf="sender.email != email.admin" class="user">
      <div *ngIf="sender.firstname?.length>0" class="firstname">{{ sender.firstname }}</div>
      <div [class.email-nofirstname]="!sender.firstname?.length>0" class="email">{{ sender.email }}</div>
      <ion-icon (click)="deleteUser(sender.email)" name="close" item-end></ion-icon>
    </ion-item>
</ng-container>
```